# Count/increment is not working in logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I filter some "status code" as output attribute from each line. like, **code = 100, code = 100, code = 200, code = 200,code =  200,code =  300**

Here, I'm trying to get the count of each type of status codes like **100 = 2, 200 = 3, 300 = 1**

The config am working on looks like,

```
filter {
 grok {
    patterns_dir => ["./patterns"]
    match => [ "message", ["%{CUSTOMPATTERN:code}"  ]]
 }
 mutate {
    remove_field => ["host", "path", "@version", "@timestamp"]
 }
}

output {
 statsd {
       increment => "%{code}"
       count => ["code", "%{code}"]
       }
 stdout {
       codec => json
 }
}
```

I know the statsd config is wrong, but couldn't fix it.

Comment: So what's not working?

Comment: I'm not getting the count like 100 = 2, 200 = 3, 300 = 1 as final output.

Comment: Ah, so statsd{} isn't aggregating the data for you.  Can't help you there, but maybe the clarity will help someone else...

Comment: yes, for now, stastsd{} is doing nothing in the above config. Need to make it work.